# How to round the results of a specific function in the easiest way?

Tags: python, rounding

I have created a dictionary `cij`  as shown in the next code. I want to round the values to the nearest integer. I have done it in my way and it worked perfectly, but I am wondering if there is another quicker and shorter method.

More specifically, I want the results of the `hypot` function to be rounded automatically without the need to list the values and then round them. Any idea, please?

```
import numpy as np

N   = [0,1,2]
xcf = [40, 50, 60]
ycf = [20, 100, 170 ]

cij = {(i,j): np.hypot(xcf[i]-xcf[j], ycf[i]-ycf[j]) for i in N for j in N }

F= list(cij.values())

rounded_cij= np.round(F)
 
print(rounded_cij)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cij = {(i,j): np.round(np.hypot(xcf[i]-xcf[j], ycf[i]-ycf[j])) for i in N for j in N }
```

This will do what you need without converting to a list. You can round it while saving in the dict itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

N   = [0,1,2]
xcf = [40, 50, 60]
ycf = [20, 100, 170 ]

rounded_cij = np.round([np.hypot(xcf[i]-xcf[j],
                                 ycf[i]-ycf[j])
                                 for i in N
                                 for j in N])
print(rounded_cij)
```

Output:

```
[  0.  81. 151.  81.   0.  71. 151.  71.   0.]
```